# calculating duration between NSDate swift 2

Tags: ios, nsdate, swift2

In notifications, you see activities that shows "posted 5 minutes ago",
That is what I'm trying to achieve here. The functions below are functioning properly.

```
func daysBetweenDate(startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) -> Int
{
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let components = calendar.components([.Day], fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])
//    print(components.second)
    return components.day
}

daysBetweenDate(postedDate, endDate: NSDate())

func hoursBetweenDate(startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) -> Int
{
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let components = calendar.components([.Hour], fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])
    //    print(components.second)
    return components.hour
}

hoursBetweenDate(postedDate, endDate: NSDate())
```

How do I recognize if the postedDate already second, minute, hour, or day old. And return whichever is necessary?

if the duration between the two NSDates are over a minute I want to output "34minutes ago" and when it is over an hour, "2 hours ago" and so on. How can I do that conditionally.

Comment: Did you try searching before posting? You might not find the answer for `swift`, but you will definitely find it for `objective-c`.

Comment: You seem to have solved the problem already. I don't see what the question is at this point.

Comment: @matt if the duration between the two NSDates are over a minute I want to output "34minutes ago" and when it is over an hour, "2 hours ago" and so on. How can I do that conditionally.

Comment: Well, think about it. If there are days, then print just the days. If not, then if there are hours, print just the hours. If not, then if there are minutes, print just the minutes. Otherwise print just the seconds.

Comment: By the way, you can get big help here from NSDateComponentsFormatter.h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give two dates, you can do this quite nicely with NSDateComponentsFormatter:

```
let form = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
form.maximumUnitCount = 1
form.unitsStyle = .SpellOut // or .Full, whatever you prefer
let s = form.stringFromTimeInterval(
    d1.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - d2.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
```

Comment: You do realize that you need to subtract the _earlier_ date from the _later_ one, do you not?